# C++: Is there a simple way to deduce return type of templated function from string?

Tags: c++, templates

I am currently writing a *wrapper* for some **legacy code**. In one part, there is a struct inside of a class that looks something like this

```
struct Data {
    unsigned int value1 = 0;
    unsigned int value2 = 2;

    bool         flag1  = false;
    bool         flag2  = true;

    // [...]
} d;

unsigned int get_uint(const std::string& name) const {
    if ("v1" == name) return d.value1;
    if ("v2" == name) return d.value2;

    // [...]
    throw "Name" + name + "not known";
}

bool get_bool(const std::string& name) const {
    if ("f1" == name) return d.flag1;
    if ("f2" == name) return d.flag2;

    // [...]
    throw "Name" + name + "not known";
}

// [many more different "getters"]
```

Just out of curiosity. Is there any way to combine the `get`-functions using templates?

```
template <typename T>
T get(const std::string& name) const {
    ``T = DEDUCE_FROM(name);''

    if (std::is_same<T, unsigned int>::value) {
        // [...]
    }
}
```

I could imagine that if I have some way to order the strings to the variables in a more centralized way. A benefit of this would be that people do not have to look through all the `getters` to know how to access the underlying variables...

Unfortunately, I am not a C++ expert. Just came from C but it seems like a problem that could be tackled by C++-magic...

EDIT:
Sorry, I just copied the names from the templated `getter`. The function names are distinct. Here, a working example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Config {
private:
    struct Data {
        unsigned int value1 = 0;      // v1
        unsigned int value2 = 2;      // v2

        bool         flag1  = false;  // f1
        bool         flag2  = false;  // f2

        // [...]
    } d;

public:

    /*
    unsigned int get_uint(const std::string& name) const {
        if ("v1" == name) return d.value1;
        if ("v2" == name) return d.value2;

        // [...]
        throw "Name" + name + "not known";
    }

    bool get_bool(const std::string& name) const {
        if ("f1" == name) return d.flag1;
        if ("f2" == name) return d.flag2;

        // [...]
        throw "Name" + name + "not known";
    }
    
    // [many more different "getters"]
    */

    template<typename T>
    T get(const std::string& name) const {
        if (std::is_same<T, unsigned int>::value) {
            if ("v1" == name) return d.value1;
            if ("v2" == name) return d.value2;

            // [...]
        } else if (std::is_same<T, bool>::value) {
            if ("f1" == name) return d.flag1;
            if ("f2" == name) return d.flag2;

            // [...]
        } // [...]

        throw "Name" + name + "not known";
    }

    
};

void random_function(unsigned int v) {}
void random_function(bool v) {}

int main() {
    Config cfg{};

    // currently:
    // const unsigned int value1 = cfg.get_uint("v1");
    // const bool flag1          = cfg.get_bool("f1");

    // works without problems:
    const unsigned int value1 = cfg.get<unsigned int>("v1");
    const bool flag1          = cfg.get<bool>("f1");
    
    // does not work but would be nice to have
    // since the strings are kind of pre-defined...
    // const unsigned int value1 = cfg.get("v1");
    // random_function(cfg.get("v1"));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you post a valid example (a [mre])? Those overloads have the exact same signature for the purposes of overload resolution, and so are not valid overloads at all.

Comment: The `if (std::is_same...` part of your template example is doable in C++17 with `if constexpr`, but the `DEDUCE_FROM(name)` part is not.

Comment: In general you can make this work if the key is something known at compile time. Your `std::string` could have come from a file or the internet or anywhere, so obviously doesn't qualify. You could always return `std::variant<bool, unsigned, ...>` (or `any`) but I don't think that's really in the spirit of the question

Comment: How is the name string created? Maybe refacto is not done at right level.

Answer (score 1):

No. C++ is a compiled language with a strong type system. `get_bool` is compiled to return a `bool`. The return type of your `get()` can only be determined at runtime.

Of course, you could return a `std::variant<bool, unsigned int>`, but that seems to defeat the point of the exercise.

There's one trick you do have: you might be able to deduce the return type from the required conversion. That is to say, in `const unsigned int value1 = cfg.get("v1");` you'd deduce that the requested type is `unsigned int`. You do this by returning a helper class from `get`. The helper class just stores the `Config` (by reference, smart pointer, copy, details don't really matter). This helper class has an `operator unsigned int() const` conversion, which works like your `get_uint`, and an `operator bool() const` which works like your `get_bool`.

Note that this will still fail with reasonable expressions like `std::max(cfg.get("v1"), cfg.get("v2"))`. In this case, `std::max<T>` cannot deduce T from that `"v1"` and `"v2"`. It just gets two `Config::getHelper` objects.